# Leaflet Maps trouble on personal webpage

Tags: leaflet

I created a personal webpage on notepad++ and created links to 5 different leaflet maps on it. it works fine when you run it from notepad++. The problem is when I used FileZilla to put my files onto the school server, the leaflet map links on my webpage do not work. If I click on the link it just shows the map title not the actual map. I get errors sayin... Mixed Content: The page at 'https://tigerweb.towson.edu/sphill16/map1.htm' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Noob comment here, but have you tried adding an 's' to the 'http' in the leaflet CDN url?

Answer (score 3):

You're not the first person to encounter [this issue](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2944), but there is an easy fix. The cdnjs service hosts copies of all versions of Leaflet and serves them over https:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/leaflet

So just replace your links with the cdnjs versions, and you should be fine.

Another way would be to [download](http://leafletjs.com/download.html) the Leaflet library files and place them in the same directory tree as your local web page, perhaps in a subdirectory called `leaflet` (or whatever you like, really). Then you can change the references in your HTML to point to those:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet/leaflet.css" />
<script src="leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
```

and upload the whole project including the directory with the leaflet library files. Either way will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try removing the protocol from your includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
<script src="//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
```